# Conduit Source depending on MVar

Tags: haskell, concurrency, conduit

I am implementing a Conduit Source for some client that subscribes to a queue and puts all the arriving messages into an MVar.

The problem is that I cannot read from that MVar to `yield` those messages through the Conduit Source, as it reports an exception on runtime: `thread blocked indefinitely in an MVar operation`

```
mqttSource :: (Monad m, MonadIO m, MonadResource m) => MqttOptions -> Source m String
mqttSource MqttOptions {..} = do
  bracketP mkConsumer cleanConsumer runHandler
 where
  mkConsumer = do
    chan <- liftIO $ newEmptyMVar
    client <- liftIO.hookToChan $ chan
    return (chan, client)

  cleanConsumer (_, client) =
    liftIO.disconnectClient $ client

  runHandler (chan, client) = do
    newMsg <- liftIO $ readMVar chan
    yield newMsg
    runHandler (chan, client)
```

(`hookToChan` just tells the client to subscribe to the queue using this function: `\topic msg -> putMVar chan (show msg)`)

Comment: What thread does the client run in?

Comment: Why use an `MVar` instead of something like a [`Chan`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Control-Concurrent-Chan.html)?

Comment: Thanks @Cirdec, I was spawning the client in the same thread :) Also, switched from the MVar to Chan, didnt know about it. Much more useful for this case.

Comment: there is already a library for creating conduits from concurrent channels: [stm-conduit](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/stm-conduit)

Comment: Yep, but I'm currently doing so from [Eta](https://eta-lang.org/), it'd require to port stm-conduit @MadNat . Thank you :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comments that Cirdec made, I've managed to fix the issue.

The problem was that I was spawning the client in the same thread.

`hookToChan` was the responsible of doing so, and I was subscribing to the queue on the same thread. I've just added a `forkIO` to the `hookToChan` function, and the issue went away.